# Is there any alternative to Apache Commons SCXML?

Tags: java, state-machine, apache-commons-scxml

I'm looking for a good and universal state machine and so far I've found SCXML. It's really simple to use (I mean the configuration) but the source code is archaic - there is no type safety and all collections are raw types. I don't have to say how difficult is to find what actually is stored in those collections. So is there any modern alternative?

Comment: Are BPMNs like jBPM or Activiti an overkill?

Comment: Yes. I tried jBPM and it's huge. I need simple state machine - just like the SCXML, but better (as I said above). A good documentation would be usefull too, since SCXML has practically none.

Comment: Have you been looking at http://www.manageability.org/blog/stuff/open-source-statemachine-for-user-interfaces-written-in-java? You could also roll your own, using the State Design Pattern. In combination with enums, this can be quite tersely coded, like http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ryano/archive/2005/01/implementing_th.html

Comment: I used SCXMLExecutor from SCXML and created my own AbstractStateMachine. The result is that I got rid of non-generic collections and still can use advantages of XML configuration and implemented logic.

Comment: I've been looking at SCXML for a while, we have JBPM, but it's horrendous...

Answer (score 4):

I have used two State Machine products, where I define a product as something that
takes actually creates portions of an operational program.

1) QP ( at http://www.state-machine.com/ ).  I used this in 2006 in a Windows C++ 
   communications product.  Worked very well, but has a limited number of target
   platforms.  Overall this was the best product, but it can cost money depending
   on how you use it.

2) State Machine Compiler ( at http://smc.sourceforge.net/ ).  I am using this today
   in an iOS product ( http://dr.edgemoor.com ) written in Objective-C.  I came across
   your question while researching alternatives to SMC.  I have not found any.

SMC is less well documented, but also simpler in scope.  And it big strength
   is that it generates code for a number of languages, more than any other solution
   I have found.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I need only pure Java libraries. It means that the state machine engine has to be written in Java and it should be configurable in XML files.

Answer (score 1):

In java, Apache Commons SCXML may be the best.But you can look up something about scxml4flex, http://code.google.com/p/scxml4flex/

Comment: Since the question was specifically tagged `Java`, does `scxml4flex` really answer the question asked?

Comment: It doesn't. I guess Apache Commons SCXML is the best for my purpose but it seems that developers don't intend to refactor the code and write better documentation since they haven't done it yet.